# How to add items to a dropdown list provided from textbox?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to take values from a textbox,

and add those to a dropdown list on another page.

Comment: Values are separated by any char ?

Comment: show us the code where you need to feed your value into?

Comment: post your html code part

Comment: add the html at least o.O

Comment: If you want some answers, then give us the code that you have tried on .

Comment: Please formulate the problem in more detail, and then pose it as a question.

Comment: I have to ask again, A textbox can accept a single value. What do you mean by `values`. Is value a delimited string such `val1,val2,val3` ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this two forms:

#### HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" value="testing">
  <button id="addoption">Click on me</button>
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <select name="myoptions" id="myselect">
    <option value="1">first option</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

#### Jquery:

```
$('#addoption').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //Prevent to send the form
   var myvalue = $('input').val();
   //Now let's append an option to the select
   $('#myselect').append($("<option></option>").text(myvalue));
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WZyQ3/1/